# Playframework Ebean.Save() gives Connection Closed

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2, ebean

I have a play framework with a simple `Address` model but upon calling ebean's #save() method I get the following errors.

The database is configured correctly I think (I can read models without a problem).
My unit tests which run on a in-memory H2 database work fine.

Code:

```
  Address address = new Address(street, postalcode, location);
  address.save();
```

Play output:

```
[error] c.j.b.ConnectionHandle - Database access problem. Killing off this connection and all remaining connections in the connection pool. SQL State = HY000
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed!
```

Address class

```
@Entity
public class Address extends Model {
@Id
    public int id;
    public String postalcode;
    public String street;
    public String location;

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Estate> estates;

    public Address(String street, String postalcode, String location){
        this.postalcode = postalcode;
        this.street = street;
        this.location = location;
    }
    public Address(int id, String street, String postalcode, String location){
        this.id = id;
        this.postalcode = postalcode;
        this.street = street;
        this.location = location;
    }
    public static Finder<Integer,Address> find = new Finder<Integer, Address>(
        Integer.class, Address.class
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: The ID value of the model wasn't being generated by ebean.

Setting the auto_increment on the id field on my mysql database worked.